# Updating sql database with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm really pulling my hair out with this one. I'm trying to update my articles table.

My SELECT statement works fine

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles") or die(mysql_error());
```

But my UPDATE statemnt fails, while not throwing any mysql errors.

```
$sql = "UPDATE articles SET kudos = 10 WHERE id = 1" ;
$query = mysqli_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
```

Any and all help is appreciated!

EDIT: I'm determining it failed with this if statement

```
if($query) {
        echo 'it worked';
    } else {
        echo 'it failed';
    }
```

Comment: How are you determining that it failed? What happens when you try the query in Mysql directly

Comment: `$query = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());` <=`?` Since your working copy uses `mysql_query` - mixing both functions on one line doesn't help neither.

Comment: *"EDIT: I'm determining it failed with this if statement"* - **No** Here >>> **$query = mysqli_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SELECT statement works with:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles") or die(mysql_error());
```

and you're mixing both `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*` functions in:

(which you can't do because they are not compatible together)

```
$query = mysqli_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
      has i --^
```

and since your successful SELECT works with `mysql_*` functions, then use:

```
$query = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
      no i --^
```

However, you're better off using full `mysqli_*` functions in its entirety, since `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and will be removed from future releases.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity! I'll accept your answer once it lets me. This is not the smartest I've ever felt!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. Do consider though using all `mysqli_*` functions instead of `mysql_*` :) @TheGooch - They will be removed in future releases. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you're using `mysql_query` and in the second you're using `mysqli_query`, which one are you supposed to be using?

Comment: Oh for the love of God that was it! I cannot believe I missed that! Thanks for that!